# Was ist ein Zeitkonto?

Tags: translation, dialect, austrian

Ein Freund von mir hat einen Newsletter aus Österreich erhalten, der auf ein Jazzfestival in der Schweiz einlädt. Was bedeutet dieser Satz auf Hochdeutsch?

> Zusätzlich haben wir aber auch noch ein **Zeitkonto** ohne Losungswort eingerichtet, von dem Sie für eine ausgiebige Weinverkostung am Freitag und Samstag kostenlos abbuchen können.

DWDS zufolge hängt der Begriff entweder mit Überstunden zusammen oder er beschreibt ein Zeitbudget. Ersteres erschienen mit unpassend in diesem Kontext, letzteres mag passen, nur dann verstehe ich den Zusammenhang zu ohne Passwort nicht. Soll das ein Witz sein?

Bonusfrage: Wie üblich ist Nutzung dieser Formulierung in diesem Kontext?

Comment: Possibly it's a typo for "Zweitkonto" (secondary account)?

Comment: @MichaelKarcher I don't see how that makes the rest of the sentence any clearer. Why would I withdraw from somebody's or an organization's secondary account when attending a wine tasting event? If at all, I'd be withdrawing from my own.

Comment: Ohne weiteren Kontext kann die Frage nicht beantwortet werden. Die ganze Ausdrucksweise ist merkwürdig. Statt "Losungswort" würde man vermutlich "Kennwort" oder "Passwort" sagen, aber vielleicht ist es kein österreichischer Newsletter, sondern ein schweizer (mit  entsprechenden sprachlichen Eigentümlichkeiten)? Ich stimme für "closure".

Comment: Die Verwendung von *Hochdeutsch* als *verständliche Sprache* scheint selbst kein Hochdeutsch zu sein: es wird nicht verstanden.

Comment: @PaulFrost: wieviel "Kontext" braucht es denn für ein Wort, dessen Bedeutung erklärt werden soll?

Comment: @bakunin Wenn die Bedeutung so klar ist: Warum die Frage?

Comment: @PaulFrost: ich habe nicht die Berechtigung der Frage bezweifelt, sondern die Notwendigkeit weiteren Kontexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Satz ist bereits Hochdeutsch.<sup>1</sup>

**Losungswort**
Der Begriff [Losungswort](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Losungswort) ist ein Vokabel aus dem Österreichischen Standarddeutsch. Dieses Wort wird im Alltag hauptsächlich im Finanzsektor verwendet. Es bezeichnet das Kennwort oder Passwort, das man wissen muss, um von einem Sparbuch Geld abheben zu können. Ich kenne gar keinen anderen gängigen Ausdruck als *»Losungswort«* für diesen Zweck.
In seiner ursprüngliche Bedeutung ist ein Losungswort (kurz: eine [Losung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Losung) oder eine [Parole](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Parole)) ein Wort, das man einem Wachposten sagen muss, um Zugang zu dem bewachten Areal zu erhalten. In dieser Bedeutung ist es seit dem 15. Jahrhundert belegt.

**Zeitkonto**
Damit ist im vorliegenden Kontext ganz offensichtlich ein zeitliches Budget gemeint. Dieses Wort ist nicht *"typisch österreichisch",* sondern ein Wort, das im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum mit denselben Bedeutungen verwendet wird. Ich halte den Begriff *Zeitkonto* in diesem Zusammenhang ebenfalls für ein wenig verwirrend und halte *Zeitbudget* für wesentlich verständlicher, aber die Bedeutung des Begriffs erschließt sich dennoch ziemlich klar aus dem Kontext.

---

Die Einladung besagt also folgendes:

Die Weinverkostung dauert 2 Tage. Der Inhaber der Einladung darf sich an diesen beiden Tagen dort für eine bestimmte Gesamtdauer (die in der Frage nicht spezifiziert wurde) aufhalten. Um ein Beispiel zu haben, gehe ich mal davon aus, dass diese Dauer 3 Stunden (180 Minuten) beträgt. Dann kann der Inhaber der Einladung z.B. am Freitag zu Mittag 90 Minuten lang an der Verkostung teilnehmen, am Abend desselben Tagen 30 Minuten und dann am Samstag weitere 60 Minuten. Dann ist sein Zeitbudget aufgebraucht und sein Zeitkonto leer. Er kann seine 180 Minuten aber beliebig auf diese beiden Tage aufteilen.

Der Inhaber der Einladung kann über sein Zeitbudget verfügen, ohne beim Eingang eine Parole (eine Losung, ein Losungswort) sagen zu müssen. Er wird aber vermutlich die Einladung mit sich führen müssen, auf der sich - wie ich annehme - sein Zeitkonto befindet, in dem über sein Zeitbudget Buch geführt wird. Möglicherweise führt aber auch der Veranstalter die Zeitkonten seiner Gäste.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Der Begriff [Hochdeutsch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochdeutsch) ist mehrdeutig. Er kann die durch Wörter- und Grammatikbücher genormte Sprache meinen, die Unterrichtssprache an Schulen und Universitäten ist, und in der offizielle Dokumente (z.B. Gesetzestexte) verfasst werden. Wenn das gemeint ist, ist es besser von *»Standarddeutsch«* zu reden. Davon gibt es drei Varietäten, die sich nur in der Anzahl der Sprecher, nicht aber in der Wertigkeit unterscheiden: Deutsches Deutsch, Österreichisches Deutsch und Schweizerisches Deutsch (letztes darf nicht mit Schweizerdeutsch verwechselt werden.)</sub>
<sub>Andererseits kann mit Hochdeutsch auch die Gesamtheit der Dialekte gemeint sein, die südlich der [Benrather Linie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benrather_Linie) gesprochen werden. Zu diesem Gebiet gehören nicht nur Österreich und die Schweiz, sondern auch die gesamte südliche Hälfte Deutschlands, inklusive Bayern, Baden-Württemberg, Saarland, Rheinland-Pfalz, Hessen, Thüringen und Sachsen.</sub>
<sub>Zu sagen, dass in Österreich und der Schweiz Hochdeutsch gesprochen wird, ist daher immer richtig, egal ob man die Standardsprache oder die Dialekte meint.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Das *ist* Hochdeutsch! Das Ganze ist einfach ein Wortspiel, wo mit dem Wort "Zeitkonto" (das es in anderem Zusammenhang gibt) bzw. "Konto" gespielt wird.

"Zeitkonto" ist ein Verbuchungssystem, für Jobs die einer Gleitzeitregelung unterliegen. Da die Arbeitszeit ja nicht mehr 8 (oder wieviel auch immer) Stunden täglich betragen muß, sondern von Tag zu Tag verschieden sein kann, wird ein "Konto" eingerichtet, auf das die tägliche Arbeitszeit eingetragen und gegen die durchschnittlich zu leistende Arbeitszeit verrechnet wird: *du hast jeden Tag 8 Stunden zu arbeiten, hast aber gestern nur 7 Stunden gearbeitet und heute dafür 10, deshalb bist Du in Summe 1 Stunde im plus (die Du irgendwann weniger arbeiten wirst)*.

"Losungswort" war früher eine Sicherheitseinrichtung für Sparkonten. Man hat sich bei der Einrichtung des Kontos ein "Losungswort" (eine Art Paßwort) ausgesucht und konnte von dem Konto dann nur abheben, wenn man das "Sparbuch" (früher eine Art Heftchen, in das die Buchungen eingetragen wurden) präsentiert UND dieses Losuungswort gewußt hat.

Der ganze Satz bedeutet also eigentlich etwa: *für die Weinverkostung können Sie sich soviel Zeit nehmen, wie sie wollen*.

Comment: "Losungswort" habe ich noch nie gehört. Ist das vielleicht österreichischer Sprachgebrauch?

Comment: @KritikerderElche Ja. Siehe andere Antwort!

Comment: @KritikerderElche, in der Prä-EDV-Bedeutung (militärisch, engl. *pass*word), ist an Losung oder Losungswort aber nichts spezifisch Österreichisches.

Comment: @CarstenS Natürlich kenne ich das Wort "Losung", aber nicht im Kontext eines Kontos. Das scheint doch eine österreichische Besonderheit zu sein.

Comment: @KritikerderElche, ah, okay, ich weiß nicht, wie alt Du bist, und ich weiß manchmal nicht, ob Teile meines Vokabulars veraltet sind.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich bin ein "Oldtimer" und groß geworden in der Prä-EDV-Welt. Habe aber gerade mal nach "Konto + Losungswort" gegoogelt und sehr wenig gefunden. Der Treffer https://at.gesellschaft.recht.narkive.com/KQC18F1K/altes-sparbuch-losungswort-vergessen deutet auf Österreich hin.